# Have Button Check the State of CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android, button, checkbox

I would like to get my button (bConnect) to check the state of my licensed and authorized checkbox.

Allowing me to use an If / Else statement to open a new activity if the boxes are indeed checked, otherwise open an alert dialog and tell the user they are not authorized unless those checkboxes are checked.

```
public class ConnectAPRS extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_aprs);

        final EditText  callsign = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.callsign);
        final EditText  passcode = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.passcode);
        final CheckBox  licensed = (CheckBox)   findViewById(R.id.licensed);
        final CheckBox  authorized = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.authorized);

        final Button    bConnect = (Button)     findViewById(R.id.bConnect);

        bConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ConnectAPRS.this, Contacts.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if(checkbox.isChecked()){//Open Activity}else{//Show error}

Comment: where is your checkbox ?

Comment: Can't seem to use CheckBox.isChecked, throws an error that I can't reference it because it's being reference from a static context

Comment: declare your checkbox on top of onCreate() method

Comment: Don't use `CheckBox.isChecked()` use `licensed.isChecked()` and `authorized.isChecked()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ConnectAPRS extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_aprs);

        final EditText  callsign = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.callsign);
        final EditText  passcode = (EditText)   findViewById(R.id.passcode);
        final CheckBox  licensed = (CheckBox)   findViewById(R.id.licensed);

        final Button    bConnect = (Button)     findViewById(R.id.bConnect);

        bConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (licensed.isChecked())
                    startActivity(new Intent(ConnectAPRS.this, Contacts.class));
                else
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ConnectAPRS.this)
                            .setTitle("ERROR")
                            .setMessage("You are not a licensed operator")
                            .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if (licensed.isChecked() && authorized.isChecked()){}

                startActivity(new Intent(ConnectAPRS.this, Contacts.class));
            }else{

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("ERROR");
                builder.setMessage("You are not a licensed operator");
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                builder.setNeutralButton(
                    "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
            }
        });
    }
}
```